# "Erase customizations" button is not reverting customized face to its standard value

Tags: customize, customize-face

What I am about to say is best reproduced with an empty configuration. So if you want to reproduce this issue just back up your `~/.emacs.d` and any other init files to a different folder and try this.

1. First I run `M-x customize`.
2. In the search box I search `font-lock-comment-face`. The default color is shown as `Firebrick` and the default state is `STANDARD`.
3. Change the color to `green`.
4. Then Apply and Save. The state becomes `SAVED and set.`
5. Check ~/.emacs. It has this code inserted: `'(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "green"))))`
6. Now Revert > Erase Customizations. The face is now `-- Empty face --`. The state becomes `EDITED, shown value does not take effect until you set or save it.` (This is where I have trouble. Why is the state not `STANDARD` again? Why is the face not `Firebrick` again?)
7. Then Apply and Save.
8. Check ~/.emacs. It has `'(font-lock-comment-face ((t nil)))`.
9. The comments are now black in my code.

Why does "Erase customizations" remove default value? Why does it not revert the customization to standard state as mentioned in Emacs documentation?

Comment: Delete it from `~/.emacs` and restart? The default value is not in some database where it is looked up to set the starting value of the face. It is defined in code that is executed when emacs initializes.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. That's what I am doing right now. But the behavior of "Erase customizations" confused me and I wanted to know if what it is doing is the expected behavior. The 'Erase Customization' doc at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Changing-a-Variable.html says "This sets the variable to its standard value." but that is not what it seems to be doing. It seems to be setting the customization to nil which is what I am confused about.

Comment: @NickD Edited the question to narrow down the scope of the question better to focus on the issue that "Erase customizations" does not seem to rever the customization to `STANDARD` state.

Comment: If you don't do step 7, Apply and Save, the entry is deleted from you init.el. Exit customization and start with the first step and you will see the default value. At least this is the behavior when I do it with Version 29.

Comment: @OliverKnodel Great point! If I skip step 7, yes, the entry is removed from init file and the comment becomes Firebrick color again (standard value). So "Erase customizations" is working fine. But an "Apply" or "Apply and Save" after that applies a `nil` value for the customized face. So it looks like a bad interaction between "Erase customizations" and "Apply" features. The former removes the customization which is fine. But the latter treats a removed customization as `nil` and applies that `nil` value making the comment black. So is it a bug in how "Apply" treats an erased customization?

Comment: In my opinion, at least the message `EDITED, shown value does not take effect until you set or save it.` should be improved.